# Flutter border radius aspect

Tags: flutter, border-radius, flutter-design

Someone knows how to do soft border radius, something like that :

[image]

Is it even possible with Flutter, I can't find how.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using the `borderRadius` property of the `decoration` inside a `Container`.

For example:

```
Column(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
  children: [
     Container(
      height: 200,
      width: 200,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.blue,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.elliptical(20, 10)),
      ),
    ),
    Container(
      height: 200,
      width: 200,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.blue,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
      ),
    ),
  ],
),
```

will yield this result

[image: Example using decoration]

on the other hand, if you want to have a different color  for the border, you can try this, setting the color in the `border` property of the `decoration` property in the `Container`:

```
Center(
    child: Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
      children: [
        Container(
          height: 200,
          width: 200,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
            border: Border.all(
              color: Colors.red,
            ),
          ),
          child: Center(
            child: Text('Content...'),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
),
```

the result for this is

[image: Example using a border Color]

Comment: Thank you but found what I want whit custom ClipPath :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use ClipRect.

```
ClipRRect(
    // Change border radius and type(.zero, .roundrect, or absolute values) to get your desired effect
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
    child: Container(color: Colors.grey),
)
```

Comment: It doesn't make the same effect. The radius is too rounded compare to the screenshot.

Comment: Play around with the BorderRadius.circular, or roundrect, or zero or you can specify the values.

Comment: Thank you but found what I want whit custom ClipPath :)